# insert data in the controller in PHP using AJAX

Tags: php, ajax, model-view-controller

My controller name is 'test' and inside it is method 'store':

```
public function store(Request $request)
{
    /*$this->validate(
        $request,
        [
            'name'=>'required|string|unique:books,book_name|max:30',
            'writer'=>'required|string|max:30',
            'publisher_name'=>'required|string|max:30',
            'publisher_date'=>'required',
            'description'=>'required',
            'pages_num'=>'required|integer|between:1,5000',
            'image'=>'required'
        ]
    );
    $user =new books;
    $user->book_name=Input::get("name");
    $user->writer=Input::get("writer");
    $user->publisher_name=Input::get("publisher_name");
    $user->publisher_date=Input::get("publisher_date");
    $user->description=Input::get("description");
    $user->pages_num=Input::get("pages_num");
    $user->image=input::get("image")
    $user->save();
}
```

and my AJAX call in the view Addbook:

```
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $('#register').click(function() {
            var name=$("#name").val();
            var writer=$("#writer").val();
            var publisher_name=$("#publisher_name").val();
            var publisher_date=$("#publisher_date").val();
            var description=$("#description").val();
            var pages_num=$("#pages_num").val();
            var image=$("#image").val();
            var token=$("#token").val();

            $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                data: "name" + name + "&writer" +writer + "&publisher_name" + publisher name + "&publisher_date" + publisher_date + "&description" + description + "&pages_num" + pages_num + "&image" + image + "&token" + token,
                url: 'test/store',
            });
        });
    });
</script>
```

But I always see this error:
[image]

Please tell me the reason.

Note: An external jQuery call because the internal is not implemented.

Comment: Hi, try to copy the URL http://localhost:8000/test/store into your browser's top bar and enter to see if it returns you something, or it is indeed 404 Page Not found.

Comment: url: 'xyz/test/store'.....instead of xyz give your project name

Comment: localhost:8000/test/store isnot found because store is a method

Comment: i put my project name like u do>>>but the error dosen't change